# Are QGIS and Neo4j a good match?

Tags: qgis

I'm having some problems with Neo4j Spatial and OSM.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523109/how-to-run-neo4j-with-osm-and-neo4jspatial

I'm considering using QGIS + Neo4j is that possible?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What exactly do you want to do with Neo4j? Most things are possible, but the question as it stands it quite broad.

Comment: Thank you John, i'm doing a project about Taxi Sharing something like this http://nyctaxi.herokuapp.com/well, therefore i would like to store a portion of a map (e.g. a city) and then make a grid-partition.  Since i haven't found a solution to my problem. I'm thinking in other alternatives e.g. QGIS + Neo4j + R? or QGIS + Neo4jSpatial?